# copy value from one sheet to another based on cell trigger

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get an simple way of copy a value from a cell in one sheet to another cell on a other sheet based on cell trigger. I got simply a cell trigger event that calls a sub;

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
            Application.Run "Workorder"
            'Application.Run "'my-calc2 - visualtest2.xls'!line"
            'Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row & ":J" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Range("Requester name")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The sub I'm calling is

```vb
Sub workorder()
    Range("Requester_name").Value = Range(ActiveCell.Row, 3)
End Sub
```

But this last sub is where I get stuck, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What worksheet is `Range("Requester_name")` on?

Comment: the worksheet is called WO

Comment: You should specify that: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WO").Range...`.

Comment: I did try to address the actual sheet and a cell reference that didn't work, so instead I gave the cell a name and use that as a reference. But back to your answer, that didn't work either, it comes with method range object_global. Normally I do get far with F1 but this time no way.

Comment: Sorry I'm not getting what you mean whit this.

Comment: begin by replacing ***Range(ActiveCell.Row, 3)*** with ***Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3)***

Comment: I'll explain some more, I got my data in sheet1 and select a cell in sheet one that triggers a sub that copies data from the third column on the selected cell row to the "WO" sheet.

Comment: That seems to be working as mentioned, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - duh... I'm slow because it's a weekend :-)